# How to unbind hover states but restore it back to others?

Tags: jquery

What I would like happen is this

I hover over the elements and their captions appear. That's easy.

But I also want to click the element and keep that hover state there, while the others still have the hovering effect.

I can't seem to do the 2nd step right. I don't know how to add the hover states back on after I click other elements.

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/62cRZ/1/

Thank you

EDIT: 
Sorry for the bad description. Here's what I meant. 
Okay so there's image1 and image2
When I click on image1, the caption stays, no more fading out. 
When I hover on image2, the caption fades in and out.

Now I click on image2, the caption now stays, no more fading.
BUT image1's fading caption returns back to the original state where it's fading in and out when you hover in and out.

Comment: You mean keeping the caption on (once clicked over the image) and clicking the other maintain the caption of the first one on?

Comment: IF someone clicks once, the caption should remain visible, but if they click again, should it then disappear?

Comment: Sorry for the bad description. Here's my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unbinding the hover actions, you could add a class to the "active" caption, and then check against it in your hover actions:

```
$('.pic').hover(function() {
    var caption = $(".caption",this);
    if ( ! caption.hasClass("active") ) { 
        caption.stop().fadeIn();
    }
},
function() {
    var caption = $(".caption",this);
    if ( ! caption.hasClass("active") ) { 
        caption.stop().fadeOut();
    }
});

$('.pic').click(function() {
    //fade out all other captions that have kept their hover states/ This wasn't the first pic clicked on
    $('.caption').fadeOut().removeClass("active");

    //fade in only this caption when clicked
    $(".caption", this).fadeIn().addClass("active");

});​
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bstakes/62cRZ/9/